# Laplacian inequality in Sobolev space

Tags: real-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Is the following assertion true?

For all $\alpha>0$ there exists some $\theta \in H^2(\Omega)\cap H_0^1(\Omega)$ such that $\|\frac{\Delta \theta}{\theta}\|_\infty \le \alpha.$

Thanks!

Comment: $\alpha > $ what? 0?

Comment: Sorry, $\alpha>0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not true for all $\alpha>0$. The necessary and sufficient  condition is $\alpha\ge \lambda_1$ where $\lambda_1>0$ is the [first eigenvalue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eigenvalue) of the Laplacian with Dirichlet boundary condition. Indeed, if $|\Delta \theta| \le \alpha |\theta|$ in $\Omega$, then integration by parts yields
$$\int_\Omega |\nabla \theta|^2 =  - \int_\Omega  \theta\,\Delta \theta \le \alpha \int_\Omega  \theta^2 \le \frac{\alpha}{\lambda_1} \int_\Omega |\nabla \theta|^2 $$
hence $\alpha\ge \lambda_1$.

Conversely, if  $\alpha\ge \lambda_1$ then the first eigenfunction of the Dirichlet Laplacian satisfies $|\Delta \theta|=\lambda_1|\theta|\le \alpha|\theta|$.

Answer (score 1):

No. Suppose there is such a $\theta$.  Then there is a $\varphi \in L^\infty$ so that
$$ -\frac{\Delta \theta}{\theta} = \varphi \text{ a.e. in } \Omega,$$
which is equivalent to the PDE
$$
\begin{cases}
-\Delta \theta = \varphi \theta & \text{in }\Omega \\
 \theta =0 &\text{on } \partial \Omega.
\end{cases}
$$
Multiply by $\theta$, integrate over $\Omega$, and IBP:
$$
\int_\Omega |\nabla \theta|^2 = \int_\Omega \varphi \theta^2.
$$
Recall the Poincare' inequality: there exists a constant $C_0>0$ so that
$$
C_0 \int_\Omega    |u|^2 \le \int_\Omega |\nabla u|^2 \text{ for all } u \in H^1_0(\Omega).
$$
Then
$$
C_0 \int_\Omega    |\theta|^2 \le
\int_\Omega |\nabla \theta|^2 = \int_\Omega \varphi \theta^2 \le \alpha \int_\Omega    |\theta|^2, 
$$
and hence $\alpha \ge C_0.$