# A Laplacian inequality over a closed domain in R^3

Tags: real-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Consider a 3D-domain $\Omega = \left\{(x,y,z): 0 \leq x \leq a,  0 \leq y \leq b, 0 \leq z \leq 1\right\}$. Let $u(x) \in H^2(\Omega)$ be a function which is zero at the boundary $\partial\Omega$. The inequality for the supremum of a function is well-known:
$$\sup\limits_\Omega \vert{u(x)}\vert \leq C_* \lvert\lvert{\nabla^2 u}\lvert\lvert.$$
It is [asserted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/369797/laplacian-inequality-in-sobolev-space) that there exists $\alpha \geq \lambda_1 > 0$ such that
$$\lvert\lvert{\nabla^2 u}\lvert\lvert \leq \alpha  \vert \vert u \vert \vert.$$
Where $\lambda_1$ is the first eigenvalue of Dirichlet Laplacian. Above two inequalities will then imply that
$$\sup\limits_\Omega \vert{u(x)}\vert \leq \alpha  C_* \lvert\lvert{u}\lvert\lvert.
$$
Is it correct ?

Comment: What is $\| \cdot \|$? Is it the $L^2$ norm?

Comment: @Jose27 Yes, I presumed so. I've got it just by your comment. I've mixed up the norms here. So the inequality I claimed is incorrect. Thanks.